# What do these hallmarks tell me about my fork and spoon set?

Tags: silver, silver-hallmark

I'd like to know what those two hallmarks mean and what they can tell me about the fork and spoon they are on.

*Click to enlarge the photos*

I see 8 star 4, J *something* B. What is this something?

[image]

These are some letter I'm unable to decipher entirely.

[image]

I believe the fork and spook are silver or silver-plated metal. They are not magnetic.

Comment: I'm note entirely sure antiques qualify as history per se, but maybe. Anyway, where are they from? What kind of age? All this is relevant. Usually though, to identify antiques, you find an expert in the field.

Comment: Voted to close: Since this question gives no time or place regarding these pieces, there is no history here whatsoever.

Comment: Is this a new CAPTCHA? The second one reads like SRBRILF to me.

Answer (score 4):

After visiting another antique market I now know more about the hallmarks:

The *8 star 4* either means that the 84% of the material used is not silver but some other metals - in other words the metal mixture contains 16% silver. Or, not my case, is would be mean that 84 grams of silver have been used to create the set of objects. This is usually marked with a *84g*-hallmark which seems often misread as 840 or 849 - leading then to the conclusion that is 840/1000 silver.

I still don't know which makes *J B* and haven't yet understood the meaning of the other hallmark.

Comment: OOC how exactly did you come by this information?